# Error during snapshot using Debezium and Oracle

Tags: oracle, debezium

During the registration of the connector, I received this error from Kafka-connect debezium version 2.2-final

`2023-05-05 18:14:33,308 INFO   Oracle|server1|snapshot  Already applied 1 database changes   [io.debezium.relational.history.SchemaHistoryMetrics]`
`2023-05-05 18:14:33,358 INFO   Oracle|server1|snapshot  Snapshot step 7 - Snapshotting data   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]`
`2023-05-05 18:14:33,367 INFO   Oracle|server1|snapshot  Creating snapshot worker pool with 1 worker thread(s)   [io.debezium.relational.RelationalSnapshotChangeEventSource]`
`2023-05-05 18:14:33,407 INFO   Oracle|server1|snapshot  For table 'ORCLPDB1.C##DBZUSER.TASKS' using select statement: 'SELECT "ID", "NAME" FROM "C##DBZUSER"."TASKS" AS OF SCN 3751208'   ....`

`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed reading SCN timestamp from source database`

the connector is set like  :

```
{
  "name": "task-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topic.prefix" : "server1",
    "database.hostname": "dbz_oracle21",
    "database.port": "1521",
    "database.user": "c##dbzuser",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.dbname": "ORCLCDB",
    "database.pdb.name": "ORCLPDB1",
    "database.server.name": "server1",
    "table.include.list": "C##DBZUSER.TASKS",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.tasks",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092"
  }
}
```

any idea how to solve this SCN error ?

bigO

event being triggered